# Computation of dynamic numeric values in an if else statement - PHP

Tags: php

How would I go about doing this logic in an if else statement?

```
If numeric_field_value_1 is x
   Increase numeric_field_value_2 by ?%

If numeric_field_value_1 is y
   Decrease numeric_field_value_2 by ?%
```

***x*** is any number from 51 - 100.

***y*** is any number from 49 - 0.

***?%*** is the percentage that needs to be increased or decreased from numeric_field_value_2. For every number increase (for *x*) or decrease (for *y*) in value there is a 2% increase or decrease for every count/number. Example 53 equates to 6% increase and 45 equates to 10% decrease. Note that 50 is the base value for *x* and *y* and there is no increase or decrease when the value for *x* or *y* is 50.

***numeric_field_value_1*** is a variable which value is pre-defined somewhere else.

***numeric_field_value_2*** is another variable which value is pre-defined somewhere else.

Example:

numeric_field_value_1 = 60

numeric_field_value_2 = 175

Now 175 needs to be increased by 20%

---

numeric_field_value_1 = 45

numeric_field_value_2 = 80

Now 80 needs to be decreased by 10%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(numeric_field_value_1 > 50)
{
    numeric_field_value_2 *= 1+((numeric_field_value_1-50)*2)/100;
}
else if(numeric_field_value_1 < 50)
{
    numeric_field_value_2 *= 1-((50-numeric_field_value_1)*2)/100;
}
else
{
    //Undefined behavior
}
```

Should do the trick.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for this! It covers all condition of numeric_field_value_1 but only for 1 - 99. When numeric_field_value_1 is set to 100 it returns the wrong computation. What gives?